# wind force necessary to move large garbage bag on ground--snow covered and grass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I am wondering what handy reference figure in mph in the wind (with and without gusts) is prudent in whether to put put a 30 gallon plastic bag of standard garbage or not?? I live alone and often only put out 1 bag every two weeks. I add 1 or 2 used milk containers filled with water to help keep bag where it is place for pickup near road. I have had no trouble--Thank God-- but using this ballast-however--I thought I would asked the physics experts for a wind force in mph beyond which waiting another week would be prudent. Thank you very much for your replies!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a calculation request, not a conceptual physics question.